# loading models - threejs

Tags: three.js

I've stumbled upon an issue with loading objects into three.js viewport. Tutorials show that it's required to use **THREE.ObjectLoader()**. As far as I'm concerned, ObjectLoader was removed a few versions ago. What's the way of loading models correctly or what loader (and file format) should I use?
I tried GLTFLoader

```
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
...
let loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load('./models/object.gltf',
    (obj) => {
        scene.add(obj);
    }
);
```

It throws me **three.module.js:5562 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.**
CDN loaders can be found here - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114.0/examples/jsm/loaders/

---

Update: How to import data using ObjectLoader?

```
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js;
...
let loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

loader.load('./models/object.json',
    (obj) => {
        scene.add(obj);
    }
);

/* throws
   three.module.js:39957 THREE.ObjectLoader: Loading "Geometry"
   is not supported anymore
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[THREE.ObjectLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/ObjectLoader) has not been removed from the repository. You can use it for loading `three.js` custom JSON format.

For loading external models authored in DCC tools like Blender, the recommended 3D format is glTF. Unfortunately, you do not use the loader correctly. It should be:

```js
loader.load('./models/object.gltf',
    (gltf) => {
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
    }
);
```

I suggest you have a look at the [official documentation page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) of `THREE.GLTFLoader` in order to better understand how the `gltf` parameter of the `onLoad()` callback is structured.

Comment: Got it. But I can't find the CDN path to ObjectLoader.js . Could u help me with that, please? (If I simply add ObjectLoader.js to my js project folder that will require a lot of other imports)

Comment: `ObjectLoader` is part of the main library. Meaning its sufficient to include `three.module.js`.

Comment: Okay. If I use THREE.ObjectLoader it throws me "three.module.js:39957 THREE.ObjectLoader: Loading "Geometry" is not supported anymore.". How can I load data from JSON instead?

Comment: Or simply how to import models with no errors using THREE.ObjectLoader ?

Comment: It the message `Loading "Geometry" is not supported anymore.` appears, that means you are try to load legacy JSON files. In this case, you have to go back to release `r98`.

Comment: What do u mean by going back to r98? Is that an earlier version of ObjectLoader?

Comment: Is there any link with code I could use in my project?

Comment: I mean you have to use `three.js` version `r98`: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r98

Comment: This similar answer also helped me: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/convert-legacy-json-format-to-gltf/38445. Recommendation is to go to r98 editor: https://raw.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r98/editor/index.html and output as glb